# Discord.js - Users in a role Adden via DM

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem when I want to add a user to a role.

**My Code:**

```js
console.log(client.guild.roles.cache.get('720257839259451393'));
```

I get from the bot:

```js
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
        at Request._callback (/home/DiscordBot/main.js:127:62)
        at Request.self.callback (/home/DiscordBot/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
        at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/DiscordBot/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
        at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/DiscordBot/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1224:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Comment: There is no `client.guild`. The properties of your client are documented here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client
Remember that a single bot/user can be members of multiple guilds and each one has its own unique set of roles that can only be applied within that guild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the guild is undefined. Someone is using the command in the bot's dms. All you need is a simple if statement

```js
if(message.guild)
{
    //The command is used in server
}else
{
   //The command is used in dms
}
```

Comment: If you're triggering this in your bot's dm's, then it would make sense that message.guild is null.

Comment: How can I add a role to the user who wrote the bot

Comment: That's a tricky question. There may only one bot owner, but that owner can be in multiple guilds. Basically, the guild where these roles are to be applied is needed before we can get the member to add the roles.

Comment: The bot is only on 1 server. Could you give me a snippet of code for that

Comment: `client.guilds.cache.get(GuildID).members.cache.get(UserID).roles...` etc. GuildID is the id of the guild and UserID is the user's id. These id's are probably best represented as strings.